# Can't continue scrolling on mobile devices when a map occupy all the screen

Tags: leaflet, mobile

We have an issue on mobile which is the user can't keep scrolling if the there is a map on the page and it occupies the whole screen.

Here is the code:

```
// center of the map
var center = [-33.8650, 151.2094];

// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView(center, 3);

// Set up the OSM layer
L.tileLayer(
 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
// add a marker in the given location
L.marker(center).addTo(map);
map.dragging.disable();
map.tap.enable();
```

And here is a jsfiddle demo of the problem: 
https://jsfiddle.net/x5p2nLrs/23/embedded/result/#Result

Can you please let me know If I'm missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a typical problem that occurs in **many** websites, unfortunately.

You have a few options:

1. make the map not take up 100% of the width, so there is a little room on the side so a user can scroll
2. insert a button (an arrow, for example), positioned somewhere in the map, that lets you jump to the space above/below the map
3. Yan can set the dragging option to false, as in:

   ```
   var map = L.map('map', {dragging: false}).setView(center, 3);
   ```

But option 3 will always disable it. That might not always be desired. You could even check whether a mobile device is used, and then disable dragging.

Comment: You can use this code example: https://codepen.io/surisdziugas/pen/LzXPwz
Its a dynamic version of option 3 that also provides 2 finger swipe as mobile alternative.

Comment: You can also read this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366253/1057968
... and use https://github.com/elmarquis/Leaflet.GestureHandling plugin.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using this options:

```
var map = L.map('map', { dragging: !L.Browser.mobile, tap: !L.Browser.mobile });
```

This leads to the most intuitive behaviour I ever found. One finger scrolls page, two fingers control panning and zooming of the map.

Answer (score 1):

Copy-pasting from https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4677:

You can't both scroll the map AND the page. Try disabling scroll: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-scrollwheelzoom

See also http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-dragging

Comment: Yes, disabling the map scrolling didn't change anything. Is the scroll wheel zoom option relevant on mobile devices?

Comment: No. That's why I added a link to the docs about the `dragging` option.

Comment: disabling the dragging option also didn't work, user can't scroll down when touching the map.

Comment: See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/4552

Answer (score 1):

*According to an answer from [Mourner](https://github.com/mourner) in [Issue #2031](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2031) on the Leaflet project:*

You can simply set `tap: false` in the map options.